# Sub request in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, request

I'm looking to do sub requests in my API, to other parts of my API. I have done this before in Symfony - but I'm not sure how to achieve this in Laravel.

```
$url = route('some.route', ['param' => $val]);
$request = Request::create($url, 'get', []);
Route::dispatch($request);
```

Always seems to fail giving something along the lines of

```
Class api does not exist
```

So I've tried

```
app()->handle($request);
```

This works, but processes a request, but I cant handle any exceptions thrown (e.g. validation as the app layer handles it and throws a html response)

Handle has a signature of the HttpKernelInterface, so can take a property of sub requests and catch exceptions - but these are not used....

```
...->handle($request, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);
```

Is it possible to do this in Laravel without having to send an actual http request?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like bad design.

You should look at GraphQL if you're always implementing this.

The another way, is to move logic from controllers to dedicated classes (take a look at Service pattern). It will give you an ability to call some logic without handling another pseudo-requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging deep into the framework, it seems that this way is not possible as it stores some values as statics and they're not updated via the `dipatch()` method.

So ive created this package to handle setting and reapplying the original values.

https://github.com/myerscode/laravel-sub-request

Comment: Referring to the package implementation will it handle middle-wares specifically associated with the forwarded/new sub-request?

Comment: Hi @jitendra sorry for the late response. Yes middleware for the route you are sending a sub-request to should be applied. I have added a unit test to the package to show this.